# How can I listen to one event from two template handlers?

Tags: meteor, spacebars

For instance in the below, only the `foo` event handler is called. (Which is odd – I would have expected the `bar` event handler to be called, since the `<form>` element is in the `bar` template.)

```
<template name="foo">
  {{#bar klass="down"}}
    <button type="submit">test</button>
  {{/bar}}
</template>

<template name="bar">
  <form>
    {{> Template.contentBlock}}
  </form>
</template>

Template.foo.events 
  'submit form' ->
    alert 'foo'

Template.bar.events 
  'submit form' ->
    alert 'bar'
```

Comment: In [meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/kLwjq8N7T5fb2qwjA/event%20bubbling) with coffeescript converted to js (coffeescript package didn't work in meteorpad) your code works firing two events.  Maybe I made a lucky typo but I think maybe your problem is somewhere else.

Comment: It was I with the typo in my codebase, thank you for the repro. Both get called, `bar` event first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer of how to do so is the code in the question, which in fact works as desired. The `bar` handler is called, followed by the `foo` handler.

http://meteorpad.com/pad/kLwjq8N7T5fb2qwjA/event%20bubbling

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [this](https://github.com/aldeed/meteor-template-extension) package, with this you declare just 1 event handler, ho will be available on whatever template you want.

Example From the docs.

```
   //here we declare 1 only event
    Template.foo.events({
      'click button': function (event, template) {
        console.log("foo button clicked");
      }
    }); 

//here we inherit 
Template.foo2.inheritsEventsFrom("foo"); //where foo2 is another Template, and now have access to the event from foo template
```

Good luck

Comment: Thanks, I see how I could use this package to have the same event handler called for both templates. However, I want two separate functions to be called. The one in `bar` will always be the same, but the handlers in the templates that include `bar` will differ.